# Como atualizar as cores do background de das linhas de um listView?

Tags: android, listview

Tenho um listView que quando clico sobre uma linha, ela envia informações para o servidor que retorna um status. Eu precisava alterar a cor da linha no meu arrayAdapter com base nesta informação. Como faço para chamar o arrayAdapter da minha activity. Quando uso o tableLayout eu removo todas as view da tabela e insiro novamente, isso resolve meu problema, mas no listView se eu fizer isso da erro. Alguém sabe uma boa maneira de atualizar o listView sem ter que matar a activity e criar novamente?

Comment: No seu adapter já tem o código que troca a cor da linha ? A sua questão é para atualizar a lista ?

Comment: Tente o notifyDataSetChanged(); Você pode chamá-lo dentro do próprio adapter ou em sua activity fazendo: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 1):

Com o adapter você pode chamar o método:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Feito isso ele atualiza a listView

Answer (score 1):

Daniel,

Para implementar essa mudança de cor na ListView, faça um customAdapter que estenda o ArrayAdapter, então dentro dele você implementa essa mudança de cor.

```
public class ArrayTeste extends ArrayAdapter {

List<Objeto> lista;
Context contexto;

public ArrayTeste(Context context, int resource, List<Objeto> lista) {
    super(context, resource, lista);
    this.lista = lista;
    this.contexto = context;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Objeto objeto = lista.get(position);


    if(objeto.isStatus()){
       int cor = Color.parseColor("blue");
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(cor);
    }

    return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public class Objeto{
    private String Nome;

    public String getNome() {
        return Nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        Nome = nome;
    }

    public boolean isStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        Status = status;
    }

    private boolean Status;




}



}
```

No fim coloquei uma classe de exemplo só pra você entender.

Usando este adapter, na sua Activity chame

```
    meuAdapter.clear();
    meuAdapter.addAll(listaObjetosAtualizados);
```

O comando `notifyDataSetChanged()` só atualizará um item que foi adicionado ou removido, ele não irá atualizar uma View que já está em exibição.